# Yii Ajax - return Field with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am having issues with some `AJAX` in `yii`. In short, I have an `AJAX`call that returns a bunch of `HTML` ie a table of order items. The returned data is rows of the order items and each of these row also has `AJAX`functions. For example, you add an order item which returns the necessary `HTML` and appends the order item to the existing items. The returned row for the new item has say a discount field which also works using `AJAX`. If I add an item and then try to type into the discount field the discount `AJAX` function will not be called on the added row, but will work for existing rows. If I refresh the page and the item is of course present, the discount field works fine. It appears that all the necessary `HTML` is passed but not the `JQUERY` for the `AJAX` call.

Here is some code specifically related to this issue, again this is dealing with order items, but the code specifically allows creation of a row and creates an `AJAX` delete button at the end of the row. This button does not work until the page has refreshed.

The view has the following:

```
  /*
  ** This is used to pull in the items.
  */
  echo '<div id="order_items">';

   echo OrderItems::model()->createEngineerOrderForm($model->order_id);

   echo '</div>';
```

Here is a sample of the code in the method:

```
$field .= '<div class="small-1 columns">'.Chtml::textField('',$item->qty,array('disabled'=>true)).'</div>';
        $field .= '<div class="small-1 columns">'.CHtml::ajaxLink('&nbsp;',Yii::app()->createUrl('Orders/removeOrderItem'),array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'dataType'=>'json',
                            'data'=>array('item'=>$item->id),
                            'success'=>'function(data){

                                                        if(data.save == true)
                                                        {
                                                            $("#order_items").html(data.items)
                                                            $("#info-flash").html("<div class=\"alert-box success\">" + data.message + "<a href=\"#flash-div\" class=\"flash_close\" id=\"close_btn\"></a></div>");  
                                                            $("#close_btn").click(function(){ $(".alert-box").fadeOut("slow"); });
                                                            return false; 
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            $("#info-flash").html("<div class=\"alert-box alert\">" + data.message + "<a href=\"#flash-div\" class=\"flash_close\" id=\"close_btn\"></a></div>");  
                                                            $("#close_btn").click(function(){ $(".alert-box").fadeOut("slow"); });
                                                            return false; 
                                                        }


                                                    }'),
                    $htmlOptions=array ('class'=>'delete-button','confirm'=>($item->rl_products->is_installation == 2) ? Yii::t('app','misc.order_delete_install') : Yii::t('app','misc.order_delete'),'id'=>'delete_'.$item->id)).'</div>';





        $field .= '</div>';
    }



    return $field;
```

Here is a sample of code for the delete call:

```
if($item->save())
        {
            $linked = OrderItems::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'linked = :linked AND status_id = 1 AND order_id = :order_id','params'=>array(':linked'=>$item->id,':order_id'=>$item->order_id)));
            foreach($linked as $link)
            {
                $link->status_id = 3;
                $link->save();
            }

            echo json_encode(array('save'=>true,'message'=>Yii::t('flash','orderitem_removal_success'),'items'=>OrderItems::model()->createEngineerOrderForm($item->order_id)));

        }
```

Hopefully this makes sense, but any questions let me know.

**Update**

Here is a small example you can test to see the issue I am referring to. Effectively here you should have a button, Button A, you press Button A and another button, button B appears. You then press Button B and it should `alert` "Successful". The first ajax call from Button A works, but the second ajax call from Button B does not.

Here is the **view** code:

```
<?php

echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Button-A',
CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/Accounts/testAjax')),
array('success'=>'function(data)
                               {
                                   $("#button-test").html(data);
                                }',
 'type'=>'POST'),array('id'=>'button-a'));



?>
<div id="button-test"></div>
```

Here is the **Controller** code:

```
public function actiontestAjax()
{
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Button-B',
CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/Accounts/testAjax2')),
array('success'=>'function(data)
                     {
                         alert(data);
                     }','type'=>'POST'),array('id'=>'button-b'));

}

public function actiontestAjax2()
{
    echo successful;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your controller action code that is used to handle the AJAX call?

Comment: @topher I have included a small example for testing purposes to show the issue. Please see the update section of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer for this after searching every variation that I could think of. The issue seems to be explained here:

https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=38

Specifically this paragraph:

> Issues are also found in widget classes. We need a better solution.
>
> The cause of this issue is that js in "ready" function is called before the ajax
>   "update/replace" is performed. Therefore, the expected onclick and other event
>   handlers are not hooked to the corresponding HTML elements generated by ajax "update/replace".
>
> A possible solution to this problem is that we wrap those js inside a function and
>   register this function to "ready". For ajax "update/replace", we explicitly call this
>   function. A potential problem is that an onclick handler might be registered multiple
>   times.

The page offers a few solutions, but in short, the solution is to use `renderPartial` like so:

```
$this->renderPartial('wdcalendar.views.default.engineer_files.render_form',array('model'=>$event),false,true);
```

Place the code necessary into the view page and then echo `renderPartial` in the controller and then using the ajax success we can replace the html with the new rendered content.

The false, true at the end is especially important in this circumstance.